# Tool for creating object representations for Entities in Dynamics

Tags: visual-studio, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dto

Similar to Entity Framework I would like to know if there is a tool or nuget package I can use where I can just send the Dynamics URL and credentials in order to create object models from a Dynamics System. I'm trying to avoid creating custom DTOs.

Comment: There is also a commercial Visual Studio add-on called [XrmToolkit](https://xrmtoolkit.com) that has the capability to generate early bound classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CrmSvcUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/create-early-bound-entity-classes-code-generation-tool) to generate strongly-typed classes for entities.

Command line:

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:http://<serverName>/<organizationName>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc    /out:<outputFilename>.cs /username:<username> /password:<password> /domain:<domainName>    /namespace:<outputNamespace> /serviceContextName:<serviceContextName>
```

GUI: (by Daryl from community)

[Early Bound Generator](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/DLaB.Xrm.EarlyBoundGenerator/) in XrmToolbox & its [video tutorial + documentation](https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools/wiki/Early-Bound-Generator)

Answer (score 1):

Early Bound Generator included in the XrmToolbox is the simplest. https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/

Find the right configuration then take the command line and include it in a batch file under source control. You'll have to run it each time you add fields in CRM, depending on your needs. If you lose your starting configuration, your code might not be compatible the next time you generate.